# What packages I need to add this style to my books?

Tags: packages, book-design

I want to imitate **this** style(chapter in letters, two lines, and the chapter's title in the middle of the lines like the image) in my books and documents with chapters. Any tips? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: That is the `memoir` class using its build in chapter style `demo3`

Comment: @daleif That’s a lot simpler than what I came up with. :)

Comment: @daleif Thanks, already reading about memoir class!

Comment: @Davislor you'd have got there quicker if the OP had mentioned that he was showing the memor manual https://texdoc.org/serve/memdesign/0  :-)

Comment: @daleif Do you want to make that an answer? We normally close questions answered in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I happen to know that the image is taken from the memoir manual. The chapter style shown here is called `demo3`. Thus getting this style is very easy

1. Use the memoir class
2. Place `\chapterstyle{demo3}`  in your preamble